# Webview response lag after going back from new intent

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview, flutter-inappwebview

So, I have this issue when I open new intent (to pass direct link and watch video in external app) and then when i go back to flutter app (lets say after couple of minutes) app feels really slow.

I need to wait even couple seconds to switch website after simple button click. This behavior persists and the easiest way to fix this is to open app again. To make this even funnier - on one router this issue exists but on another not at all (even though both of them are equally fast)..

I have this issue from inappwebview 4.x (right now I'm on 6.0.0-b23).

Here is the code I use to launch new intent:

```
AndroidIntent(
  action: 'action_view',
  type: "video/*",
  data: url,
  arguments: {'title': title},
).launch();
```

Any ideas what's wrong?
Should I use some flags? Maybe I should launch this intent in isolate? Use background service to prevent flutter app from sleep? Or maybe there is better way to launch external app and pass some args?